# Multi level Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

How to do multi level Serilog?, like how if I want to log Warning, Error, and Fatal only? can I just set it to MinimumLevel.Warning, like below?

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
{
    config.WriteTo.PostgreSQL(pgSQLConnectionString, "serilogs", needAutoCreateTable: true)
    .MinimumLevel.Warning();
});
```